# SQL for in-depth searches

Tags: sql

I am trying to write some `SQL` to return information from an in-depth search.

I have tables of names of people which contain all the people that they know and details about them.

I want to have be able to enter, say, one name as the identifier in the `SQL` for the return to be not only all the people that the specified person knows but all the people that the 'known people' know.... and all the people that they know and so on. Is it possible for `SQL` to be written to return this and if so can I set the depth of the search?

I currently have this as separate tables for each person but will happily change this if there is a more viable approach
I would simply like a list of names returned.

Comment: Add table description, sample data, expected result. Tag dbms product used.

Comment: Yes you can do it with recursive queries...and you can set the depth too to prevent it from infinite one.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?